# RxJava2 and Android complex observable chaining

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have been working with Rx Java 2 for awhile but recently came across a situation that has stumped me. I have a semi-complex chain of operations and wish to pass a "state object" down the chain.

[image: Basic flow for rx operations]

There are 4 operations during which I wish to repeat operations 2 and 3 (serialy, not together) until certain conditions are true. I know i can solve this by chaining each operation using andThen(), but this limits my ability to pass a state object down the chain without reaching outside of the chain.

The reason I need to have a state object is because I need to save an initial value during the first operation and compare it to a value recieved during operation 4 to determine if the overall procedure was successful.

Any clues as to what RxJava2 operators can help me achieve the proper repeat conditions for operation 2 and 3? I would prefer to not nest observables if possible.

Comment: Why don't you just create a wrapper object and bundle everything inside it?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your state as some `AtomicReference<State>` and use `repeatUntil` operator.

```
 AtomicReference<State> state = new AtomicReference<>();
 Completable operation = Completable.create() // do something and modify state
        .repeatUntil(() -> state.get() == SATISFYING_CONDITION);
```

You can easily chain these Completables with `andThen`

Comment: To me this seems to still be along the lines of "reaching outside the chain"

Comment: Change you definition of "outside". Perhaps you can wrap the observer chain and the atomic reference into a class for which this is its sole responsibility.